# Get specific type of events Facebook using graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am trying to get only sport type facebook events.

I am retreiving my events using the query below, but I want to filter these out by category. I have tried nested fields but I can't get the ones I need, I get everything back.

```
search?q=Brasov&type=event&fields=name,start_time,id,cover,owner
```

The events I am looking for have this category in the owner field.

```
"category": "Sports/recreation/activities", 
"category_list": [
          {
            "id": "186982054657561", 
            "name": "Sports & Recreation"
          }
```

Do you know any way I can get only the events that have this category_list id ?

Comment: That is not possible using the currently implemented search functionality. You have to filter the results on your end.

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this?

Comment: nope... Facebook does not allow this type of search.

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible. I would suggest you to store the events you received from the API call and do a filter on your server (or client).